# Fill a plot with color from a y upwards to infinity

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to indicate a "dangerous" zone in my sns boxplot.

So far this is what i came up with:

```py
plt.fill_between([0, 6], [danger, danger], danger * 1.2, color='salmon', alpha=0.5)
```

But since I use `sns` boxplot, the x values are totally messed up and i had to play with it to get the following result:

[image]

I cant really increase the polygon size as the plot grows with it (understandingly).
Ideally i would have wanted to simply paint everything above this threshold as red like so:
[image]

Comment: Usually, people save the x and y limits in variables, then add the `fill_between`, and then set the original limits again.  The upper y limit and the x limits can be used in the `fill_between`

Comment: You want [`axvspan`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.html) here